# Rounded bottom border for div

Tags: css, html, css3pie

[image]I am trying to round in the bottom border of a `div`. Is it possible to do with css? I know you can round in corners with:

> border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;

I guess I am trying to achieve the inverse of this.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show a picture of what you're thinking? The effect might be possible to reproduce with a little extra HTML or something... but you can't manipulate the border itself in the way that you probably want.

Comment: Hi, I have drawn an example. Thanks

Comment: Ah, I see. You wouldn't be able to do that w/o a background-image or a canvas/svg element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it's "possible". Overlay divs.

http://jsfiddle.net/jprGx/3/

```
.outer {
    width: 50px; 
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    border: #000 1px solid;
}

.inner {
    position:absolute;
    background: #fff;
    height: 20px;
    width: 50px;
    bottom: -1px;
    left: -1px;
    border-left: #000 1px solid;
    border-top: #000 1px solid;
    border-right: #000 1px solid;
    border-top-right-radius: 25px;
    border-top-left-radius: 25px;
}
```

Comment: It's probably not going to work for exactly what you needed, but, it was a fun exercise anyway. :)

Comment: Great solution, You can also replace the .inner with .outer:after for more simplicity (forgoes backward compatibility).

Answer (score 1):

```
.round{
   border-radius: 0px 0px -50px -50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more simple and easier way to do this would to implicitly code by:

```
    .round{
    border-radius: 0px 0px 50px 50px;
    }
```

Border-radius: 0px (top left corner) 0px (top right corner) 50px (bottom left corner) 50px (bottom right corner)